# jQuery with Shopify Slate Theme

Tags: webpack, shopify, es6-modules

I am using Shopify Slate 1.0.0-beta.15 to build a custom Shopify theme.

I have added jQuery as a node module and am including it in my theme.js file:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

** UPDATED **

slate.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  'cssVarLoader.liquidPath': ['src/snippets/css-variables.liquid'],
  'webpack.extend': {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        jquery: path.resolve('./node_modules/jquery'),
        'lodash-es': path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash-es'),
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.$": "jquery"
     })
    ]
  }
};
```

This works fine when using jQuery within this js file, but as soon as I try to use jQuery inside a template file I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

How can I use jQuery in template pages? I know I could include it in my page head but would prefer to stick with package management if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to expose the jQuery to the global scope.

You can add the following in your webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('jquery'),
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'jQuery'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works fine for js files that are built with Webpack. But if I want to use jquery within the html page content I am still getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Pedro Did you tried `jQuery` instead of `$` since we are attaching `jQuery` here not `$`?